# mysqldumpslow: What does these fields indicate..?

Tags: mysqldumpslow

Recently we have started on optimizing live slow queries. As part of that, we thought to use mysqldumpslow to prioritize slow queries. I am new to this tool. I am able to understand some basic info, but I would like to know what exactly the below fields in the out put will tell us.

OUTPUT:    Count: 6  Time=22.64s (135s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=1.0 (6)

What about the below fields ?

```
Time : Is it the average time taken of all these 6 times of occurance...?
135s : What is this 135 seconds....?
Rows=1.0 (6): again what does this mean...?
```

I didn't find a better explanation. Really thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY

Comment: 135/6 = 22.64, so it's probably the average.

Comment: So it is the total time taken across all the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I made a research for that coz i wanted to know that too.
I have a log from a pretty highly used DB server.
The command mysqldumpslow has several optional parameters (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html), including sort by (-s)
thanks to many queries I can work with, I can tell, that:
value before brackets represents an average value from all the same queries within to group ('count' in total) and the value within brackets is the maximum value of one of the queries. Meaning, in your case:
you have a query that was called 6 times, it is executed within 22.64 seconds (average), but once it took about 135 seconds to execute it. The same applies for locks (if provided) and rows. So most of the time it returns about one row, however it returned 6 rows at least once