# Interpreting mysqldumpslow results

Tags: php, linux, mysql, mysqldumpslow

I have modified `mysql` config to log slow queries

```
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

And interpreting them with `mysqldumpslow`. One of the results is as follows

```
Count: 28  Time=0.21s (5s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=5.0 (140), root[root]@localhost
```

**Question:** what do the numbers in brackets mean?

The query does take about 0.21s when run with `mysql` (or via `mysql` GUI's); however when making a request to a page the time span is more like 5 seconds.

Extra read: [mysqldumpslow: What does these fields indicate..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070098/mysqldumpslow-what-does-these-fields-indicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the number in brackets (5s) is the average `Time` multiplied by `Count` and floored.

```
28 * 0.21 = 5.88s ~ 5s
```

The same applies to rows

```
28 * 5.0 = 140
```

Answer (score 0):

values within brackets represent maximum value that happened within a group of queries, while the value before brackets represents the group's average value. In your case:
You have a group of query that was called for 28 times, an average time to execute it was 0.21 seconds, however (at least) once it took 5 seconds. Skipping lock (working the same way), the query usually returns 5 rows, although it returned 140 rows once